# background img convert to wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

all my site converted to wordpress, imgs, css, fonts, icons, but all the background: url('../images/bg); not converted,
what i n

```css
#divider {
    background: url("../images/about-bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
    
#contact {
        background: url('../images/contact-bg2.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        color: #ffffff;
}

#newsletter {
        background: url('../images/newsletter-bg2.jpg') center center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 120px;
        padding-bottom: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Im finish to converted the website and all the website files converted and only the background image not

Comment: So did you make a custom theme? What is the full directory path of your images folder you are trying to link to

Comment: yes all the images link to website but the backgrounds images not

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are asking for here. Open the console and check if there's any error when trying to load the images. Also, i guess it's something to do with the path of the image. Be sure that the path is correct in your css. Sorry but with this little details is pretty hard to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these styles have been added to the `style.css` in the **theme folder** and the images are inside the folder called `images` on the **theme folder**, the background URLs need to defined as `background: url('images/contact-bg2.jpg');`

However if you are have added these styles to the header of template files themselves then the best way would be to give the full path using `get_template_directory_uri()` function.

```
background: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/contact-bg2.jpg');
```